# Ionic 3 Keyboard auto hides immediately

Tags: android, ionic-framework, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, openid-connect

In our Ionic 3 app we have an issue with the keyboard.
Once we set the focus on an ionic input the keyboard comes up, but closes immediately.  This issue only happens on android devices, in iOS we don't have any issues.

Does anyone had this same issue?

Answer (score 0):

After two days of searching the root of this issue, we have finally found the cause.
We are using oidc-client for authentication.
There is an option: MonitorSession.
When this option is enabled, it will put an iframe in the index.html.
This iframe causes the problems with the keyboard.

Disabling this feature solved the issue.